# Images Not Displaying On Product Pages? Failed to load resource

Tags: product, product-images

On the majority of my product pages, the product image loads. However, on certain pages it shows no images.

[image]

Examples:
https://www.midselec.co.uk/brushed-nickel-3-blade-ceiling-fan-52-inch-with-light-alloy
https://www.midselec.co.uk/westinghouse-capitol-ceiling-fan-with-light-42-inch-gun-metal

Working:
https://www.midselec.co.uk/halley-brushed-nickel-ceiling-fan-with-light-48-inch
https://www.midselec.co.uk/airforce-hand-dryer
https://www.midselec.co.uk/chrome-industrial-3-blade-ceiling-fan-48-inch

I inspected the page and it seems the images located in /cache cannot be served
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**

Answer (score 0):

It seems .htaccess file missing in the pub/static folder on the server.

Please get .htaccess file from fresh download and add to pub/static folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of `/magentorootfolder/pub/media` folder. If permissions are proper, then you will have to fire `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` command, from magento root folder, this command will regenerate images. Also, this process will take some time, as it will generate all images again.